# Avoid circular dependency in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Assume I have two entities: `Nationality` and `Employee` with relationship 1:n.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // More Properties

    public virtual Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
}

public class Nationality
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In order to use Code-First with Entity Framework, I have to add one more property: `Employees` which I don't expect into `Nationality` (it creates circular dependency):

```
public class Nationality
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // How to avoid this property
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

So that I can configure the relationship 1: n in Configuration class:

```
internal class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);

        HasRequired(e => e.Nationality)
          .WithMany(e => e.Employees)
          .Map(c => c.MapKey("NationalityId"));

        ToTable("Employees");
    }
}
```

Is there any other approach which I can avoid circular dependency and eliminate property `Employees` out of `Nationality` class?

Comment: I cannot understand how *hiding* the Collection solves the circular dependency problem. Could you explain a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `WithMany()` overload to configure the mapping.

```
internal class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);

        HasRequired(e => e.Nationality)
          .WithMany()
          .Map(c => c.MapKey("NationalityId"));

        ToTable("Employees");
    }
}
```